# JavaScript AutoClick on Link in Table without cell ID

Tags: javascript

How is to make an autoclick function with JS if only the ID of the Table is set but no id for the cell? The clicker should always click on the first link of last column.

```
 <table id="sometable" width="450" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where is your JavaScript code? You should post (edit into your question) what you've tried and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors in jQuery:

```
$("#sometable tr:last a").click();
```

In this case you get the anchor in the last table row.

Comment: @DerAdmin81: Did this solve you issue? Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

**Markup**:

```
<table id="sometable" width="450" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td><a href="#">link</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">link</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
doClick();
function doClick()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById("sometable");
    var links = tbl.getElementsByTagName("a");

    if (links.length > 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
        {
            if (i == links.length - 1)
            {
                links[i].click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hFA4w/

This code gets all the links in the table, and finds the last one, and triggers the click.